# Media Queries are not working for different screens

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have written media queries for 1200px. This is working fine for 1200px but as I am changing to 1250px it is not working. all the elements get disturbed.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px)
.sticky1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 58%;
    margin-top: 47%;
    width: 30%;
}
.growthp1 p {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -25%;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: 45%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 growthp1">
      <p>The legal entity was incorporated.</p>
     <img src="images/growth/8.png" class="sticky1 img-fluid">
     <img src="images/growth/3.png" class="growthp1img img-fluid">
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">    
       </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of 1200px in which it is working]
[image: Screenshot of 1250px in which it is not working]

Comment: yes this is media for min-width.. your code work on after 1250px screen ..you should add max-width

Comment: I have added this also max-width 1250 px but it is not working in that way also

Comment: omg you miss that { open ... you should add {

Answer (score 1):

You missed that {

**Css**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
.sticky1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 58%;
    margin-top: 47%;
    width: 30%;
}
.growthp1 p {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -25%;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: 45%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for Laptop

/* ----------- Non-Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
.sticky1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 58%;
    margin-top: 47%;
    width: 30%;
}
.growthp1 p {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -25%;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: 45%;
}
}

/* ----------- Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
.sticky1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 58%;
    margin-top: 47%;
    width: 30%;
}
.growthp1 p {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -25%;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: 45%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all I want to inform you that you missed the `{` first complete this and then follow the below code as per your requirement. you don't need to use:

`@media screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) and (max-device-width: 1600px)`

this code just apply css between `1200px - 1599px` and that not a good way for you, because this will require more media query need to apply in your code.

so u can use following method to apply media query to your page.

for using `@media(min-width: value){}`:

```
// First Priority
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    //your css code
}
// Second Priority
@media (min-width: 1250px){
    //your css code
}
```

this media query is work for the screen size 1200 & more than 1200.

for using `@media(max-width: value){}`:

```
// First Priority
@media (max-width: 1249px){
    //your css code
}
// Second Priority
@media (max-width: 1199px){
    //your css code
}
```

this media query is work for the screen size less than 1200.

try to understand the above logic and if you have any question you can ask me by commenting on this answer, I will replay you for your any doubts.

Thank You...

Comment: Yes if I use 1200px then it should work for 1200px and more than 1200px screen sizes but they aren't working as I am going to 1250px or 1300px it gets disturbed.

Comment: can you please share your 1250px css code as it is in your question snippet because right now I cant see your code in it.

Comment: If you're able to see the above images then the first one is 1200px and the second one is 1250px. So if I am using media queries like this @media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) then the same code should work between these screen sizes but if you can see both the images blue line image is not stuck with the round image(2006). So how it can be done that these two images 2006 and a blue line will remain stick with each other in every screen.

Comment: I was just edit my ans please try to use for your reference, I hope this will help you to solve your problem. Thank You.

Comment: does it helpful to you bro or not?

Comment: No, it is working fine only for one screen size if we go up and down then the design is getting disturbed.

Comment: can you please generate your snippet with no errors right now it give image path error. because i don't understand that what you are needed exactly.

Comment: Check this link http://godsownbrandy.com/indospirit-project/growth_timeline.html in inspect mode. I have written media queries between 1201px to 1920 px but it is not responsive. Do you have any idea where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `position : absolute` then top , left,right,bottom will work not margin-top, margin-left,margin-right,margin-right.
 kindly use top , left,right,bottom then working

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
.sticky1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 58%;
    top: 47%;
    width: 30%;
}
.growthp1 p {
    position: absolute;
    left: -25%;
    font-size: 23px;
    top: 45%;
}
}

<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 growthp1">
                  <p>The legal entity was incorporated.</p>
                    <img src="images/growth/8.png" class="sticky1 img-fluid">
                    <img src="images/growth/3.png" class="growthp1img img-fluid">
                </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">                
                            </div>
</div>
```

[image]

check 1250px screen size are working on my device.

Comment: This is working fine only on 1200px screen size but if you for 1250px or 1300px then you see that both the images are not stick to each other as in the first image above

Comment: i have update screen where your media query is working on 1250px size. kindly check.